# how to combine and with or in an elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm working on a product search function using elasticsearch and am having trouble figuring out how to represent the following logic in a nested query:

(A or B) && (C or D)

I want this to work like a traditional programming language where it must match one of each set of or conditions in order for the product to be a match (e.g., I don't want the or conditions to just boost the score I want the products that don't match at least one condition to not be selected).

In my particular case A,B,C,D are all tests against a nested property (a list of category records).

Here are two sample index records to illustrate:

```
{
  "ProductId":1111,
  "Name":"First Product",
  "AllCategories":[
    {"CatId":15,"CatName":"Some Tag Name", "ParentCatId":99, "ParentCatName":"Tags"},
    {"CatId":352,"CatName":"Some child menu", "ParentCatId":88, "ParentCatName":"Some parent menu"}
        ]
},

{
  "ProductId":2222,
  "Name":"Second Product",
  "AllCategories":[
    {"CatId":20,"CatName":"Some Tag Name2", "ParentCatId":99, "ParentCatName":"Tags"},
    {"CatId":352,"CatName":"Some child menu", "ParentCatId":88, "ParentCatName":"Some parent menu"}
        ]
}
```

I've tried lots of different variants of my query but haven't been able to find one that works the way I want.  This ticket is asking the same basic question but the only provided answer isn't working for me (my code below is modeled after the answer from this ticket:  [Elastic search combine two must with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43410590/elastic-search-combine-two-must-with-or)

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
         {
            "nested":{
               "path":"AllCategories",
               "query":{
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "bool":{
                              "minimum_should_match": 1,
                              "should":[
                             {"term":{"AllCategories.CatId":{"value":352} } },
                        {"term":{"AllCategories.ParentCatId":{"value":352} } }
                              ]
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "bool":{
                              "minimum_should_match": 1,
                              "should":[
                             {"term":{"AllCategories.CatId":{"value":15} } },
                             {"term":{"AllCategories.CatId":{"value":8 } } }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }]
      }
   }
}
```

UPDATE:
Based on the posted answer I reformatted the query as follows but it's still not working for me.  It's the second bool inside the nested query that's causing the trouble.  I wonder if it might be an issue with testing the same field in the nested subquery in both conditions (AllCategories.CatId):

```
    {
     "query":{
        "bool":{
         "must":[
         {
            "nested":{
                 "path":"AllCategories",
                 "query":{
                    "bool": {
                     "minimum_should_match": 2,
                     "should": [
                        {
                             "bool":{
                                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                                "should":[
                                  {"term":{"AllCategories.CatId":{"value":352} } },
                             {"term":{"AllCategories.ParentCatId":{"value":352} } }
                                ]
                             }
                        },
                        {
                             "bool":{
                                "minimum_should_match": 1,
                                "should":[
                                 {"term":{"AllCategories.CatId":{"value":15} } },
                                 {"term":{"AllCategories.CatId":{"value":8 } } }
                                ]
                             }
                        }
                     ]
                    }
                 }
            }
         }]
        }
     }
    }
```

This is the mapping for the index in question

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "ProductId": { "type": "integer" },
        "Name": { "type": "text" },
        "AllCategories": { 
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": { 
                "CatId": { "type": "integer"  },
                "ParentCatId": { "type": "integer" },
                "CatName": { "type": "text" },
                "ParentCatName": { "type": "text" }
            }
        }
        "SalesRank": { "type": "integer" }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the sample products, I want the search to return product **1111** but not product 2222 (product 1111 does contain one of cat 15 and cat8.  product 2222 does not contain at least one of the two.  Both products satisfy the first boolean condition as they both are linked to the cat 352).  In my current testing, that second bool/should condition causes the search to return no results.  If I remove that one I get matches.

Comment: Can you share index mapping?

Comment: Sure thing Rob.  I just updated the post with the property mappings.  CatId and ParentCatId are both integers.  My current theory is those two sub conditions need to be broken out to two different NestedQueries but I haven't had a chance to try that to see if it works yet.

Comment: @Travis, did you see the .NET client `bool` query docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html

Answer (score 0):

this is a simplified version of what i'm running for one of my apis.

- the outer bool contains a `should` and a `minimum_should_match` of 2 (this is your AND clause)
- inside that should are 2 bool statements each contains one of the OR clauses
- each OR clause is a `should` with a `minimum_should_match` of 1
- Note: fieldA and fieldB are the two distinct fields, value A-D being the various values you want to test

```
//GET /index/type/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 2,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "fieldA": "value a"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "fieldA": "value b"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "fieldB": "value c"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "fieldB": "value d"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Francis.  I tried this approach but it's not working for me.  I added this version of the query to my post in case you might see something I misinterpreted.  My conditions are inside a nested query so perhaps that has something to do with it.  I'm also testing values against the same property in both bool operations which may be affecting things.